# How do I reverse engineer a nested if-sentence from IA32 to C?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

How do I reverse engineer a nested if-sentence from IA32 to C?

I know the if-sentence structure will take the following form, once successfully reverse engineered:

```
int test(int x, int y) { 
    int val =_______; 
    if(_______){
        if(_______) 
            val=_______;
        else 
            val=_______;
    } else if (_______) 
        val=_______;
    return val; 
}
```

The IA32 looks like this:

```
 1   movl 8(%ebp), %eax
 2   movl 12(%ebp), %edx
 3   cmpl $-3, %eax
 4   jge .L2
 5   cmpl %edx, %eax
 6   jle .L3
 7   imull %edx, %eax
 8   jmp .L4
 9 .L3:
10   leal (%edx,%eax), %eax
11   jmp     .L4
12 .L2:
13   cmpl    $2, %eax
14   jg      .L5
15   xorl    %edx, %eax
16   jmp     .L4
17 .L5
18   subl    %edx, %eax
19 .L4:
```

Thusfar I have failed repeatedly in moving the C into general goto-form that fit the assembly, and would dearly appreciate your help.

Thanks.

**Edit:** 
 1. Line 11 missing jmp target
 2. What I've tried to do is fit the outer if-expression into the following 'standard if-in-c-to-goto form'.

```
    if (!test-expr)
        goto false;
    then-statement
    goto done;
false:
    else-statement
done:
```

I then proceeded to convert the inner if-expression into the following 'alternate if-in-c-to-goto form'.

```
    if (test-expr)
        goto true;
    else-statement
    goto done;
true:
    then-statement
done:
```

After doing all this I ended up with:

```
    int value = ______;
    if(______)
        goto labelX;
    if(!_____)
        goto labelY;
.labelX
    if(______)
        goto labelG;
    value = ______;
    goto labelR;
.labelG
   val = ______;
.done
```

Comment: Line 11 is missing the jump target.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you understand the meaning of the assembly opcodes?

Comment: I've added the missing jump target.

Comment: What I have so far:

1. I split the if-structure into outer and inner.
2. I converted the outer into goto-form, then I did the same for inner separately and inserted into the outer.

Do I understand assembly opcodes? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to start from the assembly. Note that it doesn't strictly follow the C code since the default value isn't initialized up front.

I assume you know that the first two lines load `x` into `eax` and `y` into `edx` and that the return value will be in `eax` at the end of the function.

The first comparison is `cmpl $-3, %eax` and `jge .L2` so that means we have `if (x >= -3)`. At `.L2` we have `cmpl $2, %eax` and `jg .L5` where we see `subl %edx, %eax` so that's `if (x > 2) val = x - y;`. For the else branch we have `xorl %edx, %eax` which is of course `val = x ^ y;`. Okay, let's recap where we stand:

```
int test(int x, int y) { 
    int val =_______; 
    if(x >= -3){
        if(x > 2) 
            val=x - y;
        else 
            val=x ^ y;
    } else if (_______) 
        val=_______;
    return val; 
}
```

We left the not taken branch for the first conditional jump at line 5 where we have `cmpl %edx, %eax` and `jle .L3` with `leal (%edx,%eax), %eax` at `.L3`. So that's `if (x <= y) val = x + y;` (the `lea` is used as a fancy addition here). We are left with the final case for `val` at line 7: `imull %edx, %eax` which is `val = x * y`. The complete code is thus:

```
int test(int x, int y) { 
    int val = x * y; 
    if(x >= -3){
        if(x > 2) 
            val=x - y;
        else 
            val=x ^ y;
    } else if (x <= y) 
        val=x + y;
    return val; 
}
```

Since you can arbitrarily reverse the conditions there are multiple correct solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I follow what you are saying.

Should I be concerned that the book gives the following different answer:

This problem requires that you work through a nested branch structure, where you will see how our rule for translating if statements has been applied. 
For the most part, the machine code is a straightforward translation of the C code. The only difference is that the initialization expression (line 2 in the C code) has been moved down (line 15 in the assembly code) so that it only gets computed when it is certain that this will be the returned value.

http://imgur.com/wB0uaEW

Comment: See my last sentence - you can reverse the conditions, there are multiple correct solutions. You can verify that the one I have shown and the one in your image are equivalent.